# Hovering over some variables in Chrome Devtools leads to a popup with a scrollbar that covers the variable value

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Has anyone ever seen this? Do you have any idea what to do about it? I'm using Devtools with Electron.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a https://crbug.com

Comment: This was a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=599214) a while ago. It was supposedly fixed, but perhaps it has regressed.